# How to start the browsermob-proxy?

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, browsermob-proxy

I am trying to run the `browsermob-proxy` as explained [here](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy). I closed the repository, changed into the directoty

```
/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin
```

and run the following command:

```
./browsermob-proxy --use-littleproxy false -port 8080
```

and also

```
./browsermob-proxy -port 8080
```

In both cases I get the following error:

```
Running BrowserMob Proxy using legacy implementation.
[INFO  2018-01-11T13:44:30,243 net.lightbody.bmp.proxy.Main] (main) Starting BrowserMob Proxy version 2.1.4 
[INFO  2018-01-11T13:44:30,265 org.eclipse.jetty.util.log] (main) jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT 
[INFO  2018-01-11T13:44:30,288 org.eclipse.jetty.util.log] (main) started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null} 
[WARN  2018-01-11T13:44:30,386 org.eclipse.jetty.util.log] (main) FAILED SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080: java.net.BindException: Address already in use 
[WARN  2018-01-11T13:44:30,386 org.eclipse.jetty.util.log] (main) FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@4b41e4dd: java.net.BindException: Address already in use 
[ERROR 2018-01-11T13:44:30,387 net.lightbody.bmp.proxy.Main] (main) Failed to start Jetty server. Aborting. java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:162) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.4.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:356) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.4.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:240) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.4.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.4.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:269) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.4.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.4.jar:?]
    at net.lightbody.bmp.proxy.Main.main(Main.java:64) [browsermob-dist-2.1.4.jar:?]

Exception in thread "main" net.lightbody.bmp.exception.JettyException: Unable to start Jetty server
    at net.lightbody.bmp.proxy.Main.main(Main.java:68)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at net.lightbody.bmp.proxy.Main.main(Main.java:64)
```

How to fix this error, and how to run the browsermob-proxy, so I can use it to track all connections I have during a python-selenium test with the firefox/geckodriver webdriver?

Comment: You can start with different port. may the port 8080 used by any other process.

Comment: That helped it seems. Thanks...